# Using Java volatile keyword in non-thread scenario

Tags: java, caching, volatile

I understand that the Java keyword **volatile** is used in multi-threading context; the main purpose is to read from the memory rather than from the cache or even if read from the cache, it would be updated first.

In the below example, there is no multi-threading concept. I want to understand if the variable **i** would be cached as a part of code optimization and hence read from cpu cache rather than memory? If yes, if the variable is declared as volatile, will it certainly be read from the memory?

I have run the program multiple times, by adding and also by deleting the volatile keyword; but, since there is no constant time for the for loop, I was unable to come to a conclusion if more time is consumed when the variable is declared as volatile.

All I want to see is that the time taken from CPU cache is actually less than when it is declared as volatile.

Is my understanding even right? If yes, how can I see the concept in working, with a good record of the times for both CPU cache reads and memory reads?

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Test {
    
    volatile static int i=0;
//  static int i=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant start = Instant.now();

        for (i=0; i<838_860_8; i++) { // 2 power 23; ~ 1 MB CPU Cache
            System.out.println("i:" + i);
        }
        Instant end  = Instant.now();
        
        long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, end).getSeconds();
        System.out.println("timeElapsed: " + timeElapsed + " seconds.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure your benchmark, without significant changes, tests much. Are you even sure the JVM has left interpreted mode? Not convinced your code would even be JIT’ed

Comment: Yes, the variable will be read from memory because the volatile guarantees that the JVM reads it from memory.
As for the benchmark test am with @Bor

Comment: @BoristheSpider I merely assumed that the variable i would be stored in CPU cache, mainly because at any given point of time its value is < 1MB.

Comment: The value stored in a variable has nothing to do with it being stored in cache or main memory. You are probably thinking about a large array, which cannot fit in cache as a whole, but right now you have just a single int variable, which takes just 4 bytes of memory.

Comment: @Alex So, doesn't the size of the variable define if it could be CPU cached or not? This is what my instructor has mentioned in my last class. I think I need to research more into this.

Comment: by logic, there must be some disadvantage if using `volatile`, otherwise it would be the default and not even exist. By JMH test it is a big difference (factor 20 for loop and summing the variable {println not used})

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is "probably yes" ... for current Java implementations.

There are two reasons that we can't be sure.

1. The Java language specification doesn't actually say anything about registers, CPU caches or anything like that.  What it actually says is that there is a *happens before* relationship between one thread writing the volatile and another thread (subsequently) reading it.
2. While it is reasonable to assume that this will affect caching in the case where there are multiple threads, if the JIT compiler was able to deduce that the `volatile` variable was *thread confined* for a given execution of your application, it could reason that it can cache the variable.

---

That is the theory.

If there was a measurable performance difference, you would be able to measure it in a properly written benchmark.  (Though you may get different results depending on the Java version and your hardware.)

However the current version of your benchmark has a number of flaws which would make any results it gives doubtful.  If you want to get meaningful results, I strongly recommend that you read the following Q&A.

- [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103).

(Unfortunately some of the links in some of the answers seem to be broken ...)

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your benchmark is flawed; the cache is the source of truth.  The cache coherence protocol makes sure that CPU caches are coherent; memory is just a spill bucket for whatever doesn't fit into the cache since most caches are write-behind (not write-through). In other words; a write of a volatile doesn't need to be written to main memory; it is sufficient to write it to the cache.

A few examples where writing to the cache isn't desired:

- I/O DMA: you want to prevent writing to cache because otherwise, main memory and CPU cache could become incoherent.
- Non-temporal data: e.g. you are processing some huge data set and you only access it once, there is no point in caching it.

But this is outside of the reach of a regular Java volatile.

There is a price to pay using volatile:

1. Atomicity guarantees.
2. Loads and stores can't be optimized out. This rules out many compiler optimizations. Volatile will not prevent using CPU registers; it will only prevent 'caching' the content of a variable in a register 'indefinitely'.
3. Ordering guarantees in the form of fences. On the X86 in the above case, the price is at the volatile store. The store needs to wait for the store and all earlier stores to commit to the cache.

Especially the last 2 will impact volatile performance.

Apart from that, your benchmark is flawed. First of all, I would switch to JMH as others already pointed out. It will take care of quite a few typical benchmark errors like warmup and dead code elimination. Also, you should not be using a System.out in the benchmark since this will completely dominate the performance.